# How to intuitively calculate the determinant of an arbitrary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

To give some context, recently in one of our classes, our professor introduced solving the determinant of arbitrary-sized matrices. On one of his examples, he asked us to calculate the matrix 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
    9 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$
Calculating this is tedious, however, one of the students raised his hand shortly after, and answered 0, which was correct.

What I want to know is how he arrived at that solution so quickly, I want to fill the gap in my knowledge.

Comment: To perhaps give some more context, he said something along the lines of the matrices being [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8],[3,4,5,6] which led him to arrive to such a solution

Comment: Yes if you can spot that any of the row/column (vectors) are linearly dependent, then you can say that the determinant vanishes.

Comment: Yeah, he most probably did, I spent too much time trying to figure out what  'trick' he might've used to calculate the determinant, that I failed to realize that the rows were linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting the fourth row from the second gives $(2,2,2,2)$; adding twice this to the first row gives the second row. Thus:
$$R_1+2(R_2-R_4)=0$$
and the matrix has linearly dependent rows, hence determinant zero.

These operations are very easy to spot, given that the first, second and fourth rows contain consecutive integers.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response, I don't know how this just happened to fly over my head.

Answer (score 0):

Working with columns

$$C_4-C_3=(1,1,1,1)^t=C_3-C_2$$
Therefore determinant of the matrix is zero